# Saving a number of images from a set of url

Tags: python, image

I have a list `srcs` which consist of a set of url containing images which i am scrapping from and downloading it to a folder ,but it seems the image is overwritting .I am getting the image of the last url only ,Is there any way i can get the all images under folder without overwritting

Here is the code i have done so far

```
lenght=len(srcs)
elm5=soup.find('div', id="dv-dp-left-content")
img=elm5.find("img")
src = img["src"]
srcs.append(src)
for i in range(1, lenght))
   with open(images/pic{}.jpg','wb') as f:
      f.write(r.content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with open(images/pic{}.jpg','wb') as f:`
 should be `with open('images/pic_%s.jpg'%i,'wb')`

You should write each file for different src, you can use a set to make the `src` list unique, then write each request result to file named from 1 to N